# Convenient loop subtraction method in python？

Tags: python

In Python,To achieve circular subtraction of two lists, a double loop is generally used.

```
a1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
b1 = [5,6,7,8,9]
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
       res = b[i] - a[j]
       print(res)
```

output：

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8,7, 6, 5]
```

But if there are two double-layer lists that require circular subtraction, you need a four-layer for loop.

```
ai = [num0, num1, num2, num3, num4]
bi = [num5, num6, num7, num8, num9]
list1 = [a1, a2, a3, ...., ai]
list2 = [b1, b2, b3, ...., bi]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        for p in range(len(ai)):
            for q in range(len(bi)):
                ......
```

Is there a convenient way to implement circular subtraction of list elements?

Comment: try to use `Pandas` & `numpy`.

Comment: What `......` stands for? Could you please provide specific computation? Provide an example of desired output for each case.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, I will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `numpy`, the first example can be computed as:

```
import numpy as np
np.subtract.outer(b, a).ravel().tolist()
```

This also works with nested lists (second example) given the undefined `......` in the loop. Alternatively, for nested lists and not using `numpy` you can try:

```
import itertools
[x - y for x in itertools.chain(*list2) for y in itertools.chain(*list1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is indeed a convenient method.

Answer (score 1):

What about first flattening the lists and then performing the circular subtraction?

```
def flatten(lst):
    if all(type(x) == list for x in lst):
        return flatten([e for l in lst for e in l])
    return lst

def subtract_from(lst2, lst1):
    if all(type(x) == list for x in lst1):
        lst1, lst2 = flatten(lst1), flatten(lst2)
    return [y - x for x in lst1 for y in lst2]

l1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(subtract_from(l2, l1))
# [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

l1 = [[0, 1], [3, 2], [1, 4]]
l2 = [[4, 5], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
print(subtract_from(l2, l1))
# [4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

`flatten` is recursive and `subtract_from` checks if the lists need to be flattened.

Comment: Thank you for your answer！maybe my statement is not clear enough. The result I want is that all the elements in one list are subtracted from all the elements in the other list, not the subtraction of the corresponding position elements of the two lists.

Comment: @wisejay_Li Ah, now I understand. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: @wisejay_Li Is this more like your expected output?

Comment: Yes, this is the output I am looking forward to, thank you for your help.

Comment: @AGNGazer thanks, although I'd stick with numpy myself if it's available and has something built in :)